# Need clarity about CSS styling

Tags: css

I need some clarity about CSS styling. Let's create a simple example. I have a `header` div container at the top of the page. I then fill this container with two other div tags, a `logo` div and a `menu` div.

When I use Firebug or press F12 in another browser to inspect the div tags, and especially the parent div `header`, I can hover above the code and the div elements get highlighted in color.

But when I set the `logo` div CSS property to `float: left` and the `menu` div CSS property to `float: right`, the parent div `header`, don't get highlighted any more! Despite that I set the following div element CSS property to `clear: both`. Is this OK, or am I doing something wrong in my CSS? If I set a hight to the parent div, it's highlighted again.

Is there a error in the CSS, when I can't highlight the element? It's often I get this kind of "errors" when I use CSS.

Comment: You may be interested in this question - ["What is a clearfix?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

Comment: The element with `clear` must be inside the header too .... I suggest use the pseudo-element after clearfix.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to the parent div's style/class and that will stretch the div so that the child divs actually sit inside it.